# Add a Marker Inside a Polygon Depending on Where User Clicks

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Depending on where a user clicks inside the polgyon, I display an infoWindow. This is done by adding a click event listener to the polygon:

```
bermudaTriangle.addListener('click', function(event) {
    var anchor = new google.maps.MVCObject();
    anchor.set("position", event.latLng);
    infowindow.open(map, anchor);
});
```

Is there any way I can show a marker icon at the anchor point that is being retrieved using `event.latLng`? If I create `new google.maps.Marker` instead of `new google.maps.MVCObject`, then the infoWindow opens outside of the polygon, and is way off.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/2qyhkkok/

Comment: Using [a marker works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/2qyhkkok/1/), how are you trying to use a marker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the marker as the anchor for the infowindow works for me:

```js
var map;
var marker;
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 5,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(24.886436490787712, -70.2685546875),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    };

    var bermudaTriangle;

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
    mapOptions);

    var triangleCoords = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(25.774252, -80.190262),
    new google.maps.LatLng(18.466465, -66.118292),
    new google.maps.LatLng(32.321384, -64.75737),
    new google.maps.LatLng(25.774252, -80.190262)];

    bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
        paths: triangleCoords,
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: '#FF0000',
        fillOpacity: 0.35
    });

    bermudaTriangle.setMap(map);

    bermudaTriangle.addListener('click', function (event) {
        if (marker && marker.setPosition) {
          marker.setPosition(event.latLng);
          } else {
          marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: event.latLng,map:map});
            }
        infowindow.setContent("Hello, world.");
        // var anchor = new google.maps.MVCObject();
        // anchor.set("position", event.latLng);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html, body, #map-canvas {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```